# Where to store settings in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

i would like to consolidate the url base for my RESTFul API in a single place in my app built with Sencha Touch. Where is the best place i can put it?

There is a obvious option to store it in localStorage, but is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to support MVC structure I create file Config.js and put it in application tree in the following place:

[image]

in Config.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.config.Config', {
    singleton: true,
    config: { /** here you can put any objects of your choice that will be accessible globally**/
        baseURL         : Ext.os.is.Android ? 'http://live_url_here.com' : 'http://localhost/testing_locally',
        topBannerUrl    : 'http://some_url/banner.png',
        anotherGlobalParam      : true
    },
    constructor: function(config) {

       this.initConfig(config);
       return this;    
    }
});
```

Those config parameters will be visible in the whole application.

You may get them:

```
MyApp.config.Config.getBaseImgURL(); /* returns 'http://some_url/banner.png' */
MyApp.config.Config.getAnotherGlobalParam(); /* returns true */
```

or set:

```
MyApp.config.Config.setBaseImgURL('new_url');
MyApp.config.Config.setAnotherGlobalParam(false);
```

This solution may be especially handy when your project requires **many configuration parameters**.
I hope it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Always keep your url base in a seperate file like util.js(utility.js). Your file path should be app > util > Util.js. You can keep your common functions like animateItem, showLoading/hideLoading, custom functions, etc over here so that you can use the same function throughout the app. To load this file in your app do this:

**app.js**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloWorld',        
    requires: [
     'HelloWorld.util.Util'
    ],
    view: []
})
```

For best practices in sencha touch you can see this: [Sencha Touch Blog](http://innofied.com/sencha-touch-coding-guidelines-you-should-follow-part-1/)

Comment: I would add that putting such a value in localstorage wouldn't be of any use, localstorage is generally used to save user preferences or to cache stuff that need to persist between application reloads. In your case the url is not going to change, or if it changes, you will need a redeploy anyway, so you can hardcode it. Also, about the `Util`  class, I would suggest to use a class with `statics` property to store your utility functions or values.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Anubis recommendation.

Something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Const', {
    statics:{
        url1:'....',
        url2:'....'
    }
})
```

Then you can access your urls with:

```
MyApp.Const.url1
```

Of course you must require `Const` class but you don't need to instantiate it.